# Cryptic Lettering on Ubuntu Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

On the online accounts page
[image]

and the ubuntu guide
[image]
in settings there is cryptic rendering of text.

The webpages still work and I can click on things but I can't see it. The cursor also changes when hovering on buttons, text boxes etc.

The OS I am using is the full Ubuntu OS on the Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: If you use a PC or Mac do you see the same issues? Maybe this should be asked on [SE.Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)? However, do not cross-post.

Comment: I have not seen this bug before

Comment: is your system fully updated?